# the advantage of using @extend over creating class and using it in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I am new to `SASS`.
I question is why to use `@extend`  over creating a class and adding it to the element in html.
thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's considered easier to maintain if you don't have to hunt down the class in the markup should you ever need to remove or modify it. I personally prefer using extend so I don't have to have classes like `class="index-row clearfix verdana box-shadow marginless"` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It saves you from verbose coding.Adding extra markup to your HTML file is a no no.